# Solving Partial Differential Equation $ \Delta u = 4 $

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

How can I solve this equation:

$ \Delta u = 4 \\ u(x,x)=2x^2 \\ u_x(x,x) = 2x$

where $u=u(x,y)$

using substitution: $ \Phi ^{-1}(s,t) = (x-y,y) $?

My attempt to solve this:

$v=u \circ \Phi ^{-1}$

$u_x=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial x} = v_s \cdot 1 + v_t  \cdot 0 = v_s$

$u_y=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial y} = v_s \cdot (-1) +v_t \cdot 1 = v_t - v_s$

$u_{xx} = \frac{\partial v_s}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v_s}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial x} = v_{ss} \cdot 1 + v_{st}  \cdot 0 = v_{ss}  $  - is it right?

$u_{yy} = v_{ss} - 2v_{st} + v_{tt}$

It seems, that my result does not help to solve this equation, but I've been said, that it does. I think I should somehow get some informations about v (but I don't know how to do this) and then use the Kovelawska theorem. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: $\,{\rm u}\left(\, x,y\,\right) = 2x^{2}$ is a solution.

Comment: okay, but there could be more possible solutions, right? Like $ (x+y)^2 $

Answer (score 2):

The general solution of $ \Delta u = 0$ is $u=f(x+iy)+g(x-iy)$ where $f$ and $g$ are any two times derivable functions.

The general solution of $ \Delta u = 4$ is the preceeding general solution plus a particular solution. Some particular solutions are obvious, for example $2x^2$, or $2y^2$, or $x^2+y^2$, or many others.

So the general solution of $ \Delta u = 4$ can be expressed on the form: 
$$u=f_1(x+iy)+g_1(x-iy)+2x^2$$
or
$$u=f_2(x+iy)+g_2(x-iy)+2y^2$$
or
$$u=f_3(x+iy)+g_3(x-iy)+x^2+y^2$$
or many others. All these forms are equivalent, since on can chose the functions $f(x+iy)$ and $g(x-iy)$ so that one of them is transformed to another.

The functions $f$ and $g$ must be determined according to the given conditions

$ u(x,x)=2x^2 \\ u_x(x,x) = 2x$

I suppose that you can continue and prove that the solution is $u=x^2+y^2$, as obviously expected.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I have one more question: how do you calculate that the solution of $ \Delta u = 0$ is $u=f(x+iy)+g(x-iy)$?

Comment: $u(x,y)=f(x+iy)$ is a well-known solution of the Laplace's equation $\Delta u = 0$ in 2D. It is easy to see that $u_x=f'(x+iy)$, then $u_{xx}=f''(x+iy)$ and $u_y=if'(x+iy)$, then $u_{yy}=i^2f''(x+iy)=-f''(x+iy)$, leading to $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=f''(x+iy)-f''(x+iy)=0$ hense $\Delta u = 0$.

Comment: Thank you;) 
But why do we get $f''$ instead of $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$? I mean that I don't understand why differentiating over x and over y gives us the same thing ;(

Comment: Because $f(z)$ is defined as a function of only one variable $z$ what ever is $z$. In this case $z=x+iy$ is a function of two variables $x$ and $y$ so that $u(x,y)=f\big(z(x,y)\big)$ is a function of functions. For example if $f(z)=z^2$ then $u(x,y)=(x+iy)^2$ then $f'(z)=2z$, then $u_y=f'(z) z_y=f'(z)i=2zi=2i(x+iy)$

Comment: @Kuba : by the way, you wrote : <<But why do we get $f ′′$   instead of $f_{xx}$   and $f_{yy}$  ? I mean that I don't understand why differentiating over $x$ and over $y$ gives us the same thing>> No, it is not what is written in my answer : the first is $f''$ and the second is $i^2f''=-f''$. Of course $f''$ is not equal to $-f''$

Comment: If you don't understand, instead of using the "short" notations $f'$ and $f''$, use the more explicite notations $\frac{df}{dz}$ and $\frac{d^2f}{dz^2}$.